# Remove Object of an Level 2 Hierarchy Array from Document in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document as below :

```
{
  "user_id": "62f3a172783c44a77b5d94e7",
  "credit": [
    {
      "user_id": "6319af212e097afcbde1b099",
      "amount": 32960,
      "transactions": [
        {
          "amount": 11480,
          "date": "2022-11-17",
          "order_id": "6375c53e71fd183c4bfc9f21"
        },
        {
          "amount": 11480,
          "date": "2022-11-17",
          "order_id": "6375c577b48b982c83a0e5c5"
        },
        {
          "amount": 10000,
          "date": "2022-11-18",
          "order_id": "63770b9e3ea4f4c83a7cfebc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "debit": [
    {
      "user_id": "6319af212e097afcbde1b099",
      "amount": 0,
      "transactions": []
    }
  ],
}
```

I want to remove the object with order_id "6375c53e71fd183c4bfc9f21". I have tried multiple queries and arrayFilters but didn't get success.

What query and arrayFilters along with updateDocument can remove this object?

I have tried below combinations of query, updateDocument and options for db.collection.updateOne();

```
query = { user_id : "62f3a172783c44a77b5d94e7" },
updateDocument = { $pull : { credit : { $elemMatch : { order_id : "6375c53e71fd183c4bfc9f21" } } } },
options = { arrayFilters : [ { "item.user_id" : "6319af212e097afcbde1b099" }, ], });


query = { user_id : "62f3a172783c44a77b5d94e7" },
updateDocument = { $pull: { "credit$[item].transactions": { order_id: req.params.orderId } }, },
options = { arrayFilters : [ { "item.user_id" : "6319af212e097afcbde1b099" }, ], });


db.collection.updateOne(query, updateDocument, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure there is only one object with `"order_id": "6375c53e71fd183c4bfc9f21"`, here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "user_id": "62f3a172783c44a77b5d94e7",
  "credit.transactions.order_id": "6375c53e71fd183c4bfc9f21"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "credit.$.transactions": {
      "order_id": "6375c53e71fd183c4bfc9f21"
    }
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tu82tj7KyIT).